# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push') React router DOM

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I just learned react, when button is clicked I want to navigate, but it doesn't and gives an error that 'push' is undefined, how to solve it?

```
import { Route, useHistory as history } from 'react-router-dom'

export default class TotalPrice extends Component {
  checkout = (sum) => {
    const order = {
      total_bayar: sum,
      menus: this.props.carts
    }

    axios.post(API_URL + "orders", order).then((res) => {
      this.props.history.push('/order-success')
    })
  } 
  render() {
    const sum = this.props.carts.reduce(function (result, item) {
      return result + item.total_price;
    }, 0);

    return (
      <Row className='fixed-bottom'>
        <Col md={{span: 3, offset: 9}} className='py-4 px-4 total'>
          <h4>
            Total : <strong className='total-number'>Rp. {priceSplitter(sum)}</strong>
          </h4>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="button-checkout"
            onClick={() => this.checkout(sum)}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} />
            Checkout
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `history` isn't in your props. See https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/usehistory. You also cannot use hooks in class components

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying that `this.props.history` is undefined. Since it appears that you are using `react-router-dom@5` you can import and use the [`withRouter`](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter) Higher Order Component and decorate this `TotalPrice` component to inject the [route props](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/route-props).

```
import { Route, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class TotalPrice extends Component {
  checkout = (sum) => {
    const order = {
      total_bayar: sum,
      menus: this.props.carts
    };

    axios.post(API_URL + "orders", order)
      .then((res) => {
        this.props.history.push('/order-success');
      });
  }

  render() {
    const sum = this.props.carts.reduce(function (result, item) {
      return result + item.total_price;
    }, 0);

    return (
      <Row className='fixed-bottom'>
        <Col md={{span: 3, offset: 9}} className='py-4 px-4 total'>
          <h4>
            Total : <strong className='total-number'>Rp. {priceSplitter(sum)}</strong>
          </h4>
          <Button
            variant="primary"
            className="button-checkout"
            onClick={() => this.checkout(sum)}
          >
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faShoppingCart} />
            Checkout
          </Button>
        </Col>
      </Row>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(TotalPrice);
```

If you are using `react-router-dom@6` then you will have to roll your own custom `withRouter` HOC if you want to continue using React class-based components since RRDv6 doesn't export any `withRouter` HOC like v5 did, and there are ***only*** React hooks available to use in components. You can follow my answer [here](https:///a/69902006/8690857) for brief explanation and code example.

Comment: Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'.

Comment: @leo I see. Does my answer [here](/a/69902006/8690857) resolve your question/issue?

Comment: I've created a new new file for withrouter, but still can't. here is error message Attempted import error: 'withRouter' is not exported from './withRouter'.

Comment: @leo How did you export your `withRouter` function? Did you import it correctly? I.E. is it a default or named export?